# Random Categories Showing Null After DotNet 3.1 Update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

This one has been a head-scratcher for me. Still kind of new to certain things and EFCore, but I believe I have been doing well. I want to know what could have possibly changed.

I have created an endpoint that gets a specific number of list of Deals, it had been working since it's inception (DotNet Core 2.2), but after updating to 3.1, it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I know I did this in a weird way, I found it as a solution somewhere else and tried it, but hear me out. I have a Deal, that Deal has a SubCategory (which has an ID, name, etc...), then within the SubCategory, I have a Category (Which has an ID, name, etc...).

To get my specific list of Deals, I called this within the endpoint:

```
List<Deal> deals = new List<Deal>();
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    deals = await context.Deals
        Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == user.Id)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .Include(x => x.SubCategory)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Category)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

There are some other things here, but they are still working without issue that are done the same way.

Now, here's the issue. Say I have 20 deals, I load those deals up, 5 of them can't seem to get the category. No matter how many times I load the endpoint, it returns the category of null for those same 5.

Even weirder, let's say I upload a deal, now I have 21 deals, a different set of deals now seem to return category of null, not the same 5 from before. It's like it's random only when the sequence of deals has been altered in some way, so the deals that had category null before, now have the category back, and a random set of a number of deals are returning category null until a new deal is added or one removed.

I have a fix for this, in terms of deciding to use a Linq Query instead of using this, and this is working without fail, but I want to know what could possibly be causing this weird issue.

FYI... I get 0 errors when this happens, just null categories.

Comment: Did you check if the Id is set up in the object where you get null category. Also what I usually do is put all Includes right after the dbset and after call all filters, maybe you change the order it will work (don’t think so but you never know :D). Reading that you get it randomly after each insert maybe you should look at your foreign keys just to make sure they are setup right.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I just don't really understand why it would have worked prior to the update to 3.1.

Comment: If this was working properly in 2.2, and as-well going through a Linq query, then something is strange - check the [breaking changes in EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) list to see if anything there applies to your situation (there was mention of changes made to fk property convention and owned type relationships)